# Integrate BigBlueButton in Django

Tags: django, bigbluebutton

i installed **BigBlueButton** in my **Django** project and i create a meeting using the admin page. That's the meeting model showed in admin page.

| Meeting Name | Created at | Is running | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Metting 2 | Aug. 27, 2021, 4:17 p.m. | False | Create join link - Start Now |
| Metting 1 | Aug. 27, 2021, 4:06 p.m. | False | Create join link - Start Now |

But whenever i try to start a meeting an exception raise:

**RuntimeError at /admin/django_bigbluebutton/meeting/2/join/**

***No active exception to reraise***

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/django_bigbluebutton/meeting/2/join/
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     RuntimeError
Exception Value:

No active exception to reraise

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Galaxynet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django_bigbluebutton\bbb.py, line 221, in start

this is the code of *start* function:

def start(self, name, meeting_id, **kwargs):
""" Start meeting with provided info.

```
    Most of BigBlueButton info is provided now.
    TODO: will add more configs for bigbluebutton later!
    """
    call = 'create'
    attendee_password = kwargs.get("attendee_password", self.attendee_password)
    moderator_password = kwargs.get("moderator_password", self.moderator_password)

    # Get extra configs or set default values
    welcome = kwargs.get('welcome_text', _('Welcome!'))
    record = kwargs.get('record', BBB_RECORD)
    auto_start_recording = kwargs.get('auto_start_recording', BBB_AUTO_RECORDING)
    allow_start_stop_recording = kwargs.get('allow_start_stop_recording', BBB_ALLOW_START_STOP_RECORDING)
    logout_url = kwargs.get('logout_url', BBB_LOGOUT_URL)
    webcam_only_for_moderators = kwargs.get('webcam_only_for_moderators', BBB_WEBCAM_ONLY_FOR_MODS)
    voice_bridge = 70000 + random.randint(0, 9999)

    # Making the query string
    query = urllib.parse.urlencode((
        ('name', name),
        ('meetingID', meeting_id),
        ('attendeePW', attendee_password),
        ('moderatorPW', moderator_password),
        ('record', record),
        ('welcome', welcome),
        ('bannerText', welcome),
        ('copyright', BBB_COPYRIGHT_TEXT),
        ('logoutURL', logout_url),
        ('voiceBridge', voice_bridge),
        ('autoStartRecording', auto_start_recording),
        ('allowStartStopRecording', allow_start_stop_recording),
        ('webcamsOnlyForModerator', webcam_only_for_moderators),
    ))
    hashed = self.api_call(query, call)
    url = self.api_url + call + '?' + hashed
    result = parse_xml(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8'))
    if result:
        return result
    else:
        raise
```

I add those two commands to setting.py:

```
BBB_API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/bigbluebutton/api/'
BBB_SECRET_KEY = 'abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg'
```

Can enyone help me in this?.

Comment: In the Created at column you can see 'false' I am not familiar with the django_bigbluebutton possibly it will create the meeting before it starts it, however it looks like the issue is at the bbb server. If you have access to the server next step would be to run the bbb-conf steps here https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/admin/bbb-conf.html to confirm server health.

Comment: If bbb server is healthy next step would be to follow the meeting creation flow in the bbb-web server logs with tail -f  /var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.log, tailing the log try and create/start the meeting and look for 1) the request actully hts the bbb-web server, then check the meeting creation flow completes with no exceptions

Comment: @NigelSavage i made a mistake .**False -> is for Is Running** .i changed it

Comment: you wont be able to join a meeting unless its running, when you create the meeting it will run,  then you can join the meeting